# Can we delete the changes(git changes) created during the test execution instead only merging/abandoning them?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have written test cases, during the test case execution changes will be create, that changes will clean up by merging/abandoning at end. But sometimes some exceptions will raised between the merging/abandoning on clean up process.

Can we think about a way to delete the changes created during the test instead only merging/abandoning them?

```
class TestChangeMerge(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, conf, git, gerrit):
        self.git = git(config)
        self.gerrit = gerrit(config)

    def test_change_merge(self):
        log.info("STEP 1 : git-clone")
        self.git.clone()

        log.info("STEP 2 : Create commit and push new change")
        self.git.push_change()

        log.info("STEP 3 : Checking results")
         assert (self.gerrit.change_status(self.git.change_id))

    def teardown(self):
        self.git.cleanup()
        self.gerrit.cleanup() 
     #Here we have stated cleanup, used ssh command 'gerrit review --abandon', in case failed on abandon then what is alternate way to cleanup.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete changes using REST.

See how to use "Delete Change" endpoint [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#delete-change).

You need to grant [Delete Own Changes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_delete_own_changes) or [Delete Changes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_delete_changes) permission to the user who will delete the changes.

See more info about the Gerrit REST API [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the commit ID of the commit where you want to go back to. Then you can make:

```
git reset --hard commit-id
```

Or, optimally, you have placed a tag where you want to go back to.

```
git reset --hard tagname
```

If you already pushed your unwanted commit (I assume this as of 'self.git.push_change()' call), you will have to force push afterwards:

```
git push --force
```

But make **absolutely sure** that no one else has pushed to the repo in the meantime - that changes would be lost too. *Force pushes have to be synchronized with every each person who uses the repo!!!*